# Magento 2.3.1 Cloud EE configure multiple websites on one installation

Tags: magento2, multistore, multi-website, multidomain, cloud

I'm following the official [Magento wiki](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/cloud/project/project-multi-sites.html) regarding the configuration of multiple websites in Magento 2.3.1 EE cloud but I really cannot understand what I'm doing wrong in my local configuration.

What I want to achieve is something like:

domain1/it
domain1/de

domain2/it
domain2/de

So multiple websites with one store each and each store have two store views.
As you can see I need the same store code for both the websites but creating both from the admin gives an error because the variable is unique.

So I created the store views with codes like domain1_it, domain2_it.
I then specified on the admin panel both the URLs I specified above for the store views. I even un-set the **Auto-redirect to Base URL** value because it kept redirecting me while I browsed my second domain.

my host's file is the following right now: `127.0.0.1 domain1 domain2`

I can access the domain2 right now but when I switch to my store domain2/it I get an **error 404**. Do I need even more configuration?

For now, I am pretty unsure about this configuration and I'm worried about what I'll have to do for my integration deployment too.

Thanks in advance!